# Plotting resistance and reactance curves on the Smith Chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach, charts, polarplot

For my class, I have been trying to plot constant resistance and reactance curves on the Smith chart. While the latter appears to be straightforward, the only way I can think of for the former is plotting a group of closely spaced points, which becomes quite memory intensive. My questions are:

1. Is there any way efficient way to plot constant resistance curves (red and orange in this case), like the reactance curve (blue)?
2. Is there a way to shift the originating point of the blue (reactance) curve to a point say the one intersecting with the red one?

After following the answers from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264168/pgfplots-use-foreach-inside-addplot) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304026/adding-wavelength-co-ordinates-to-pgfplots-smith-chart/304032), I have arrived at:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{smithchart}
            
        % Reactance plot
        \addplot[domain=0:90, samples=600, color=blue] {.5};

        % Resistance plot - orange 
        \foreach \x in {.5, .51,...,5}
        {\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot+[mark=*,
        mark options={solid},color={orange},mark size=.2,line width=1] coordinates { (.5,\x) };}\temp}

        % Resistance plot - red 
        \foreach \x in {0, .01,...,.5}
        {\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot+[mark=*,
        mark options={solid},color={red},mark size=.2,line width=1] coordinates { (1,\x) };}\temp}
            
        \end{smithchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which generates the output below:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not really understand the question. However, one of your concerns seems to be compilation time. This code reproduces your output in a fraction of time. (Using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` without the `\edef` stuff already speeds it up quite a bit, but the following is even faster.)

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{smithchart}
            
        % Reactance plot
        \addplot[domain=0:90, samples=600, color=blue] {.5};

        % Resistance plot - orange 
        \addplot+[mark=*,only marks,samples at={.5, .51,...,5},
        mark options={solid},color={orange},mark size=.2,line width=1](.5,x) ;

        % Resistance plot - red 
        \addplot+[mark=*,only marks,samples at={0, .01,...,.5},
        mark options={solid},color={red},mark size=.2,line width=1] (1,x) ;
            
        \end{smithchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I really do not understand why you do not do something like

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{smithchart}[samples=181,line cap=round,smooth]
            
        % Reactance plot
        \addplot[domain=0:20,  color=blue] (x,.5);

        % Resistance plot - orange 
        \addplot+[no marks,domain=.5:5,
        color={orange},line width=1](.5,x) ;

        % Resistance plot - red 
        \addplot+[no marks,domain=0:.5,
            color={red},line width=1] (1,x) ;
            
        \end{smithchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for making the code many times more efficient. The reason for a loop-based approach is to eventually generate an animation showing the curves traversing on the Smith chart.