# Resource for drawing arcs of constant resistance and reactance on pgfplots smith charts

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Where can I find resources to learn how to draw lines of constant resistance or reactance on pgfplots smith charts? The PGFPlots manual does not appear to explain this.

I found this post: [Plotting resistance and reactance curves on the Smith Chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590730/plotting-resistance-and-reactance-curves-on-the-smith-chart),
but it draws arcs as a set of points rather than a continuous line.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: The linked post does seem to draw continuous curves. Could you please explain in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: PGFplots always draws lines by connecting coordinates. The more coordinates you have, the smoother the line will get.