# Plot with increments

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to adapt the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59927/93163) to be inside a pgf axis and use axis coordinates. The solution is based on a `draw` command like the following

```
\draw (0,0) \foreach \x in {1,...,5} { -- ++ (1,0.1*\x)};
```

where the increments are specified instead of points.

I tried using the `addplot` command instead of `draw` (So I can specify axis coordinates). However I am running into problems. First the following simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [mark=*] (0,0) -- ++(0.1,0.1) -- ++(0.3, -0.4);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

compiles but the plot is not correct and I get the warning

```
Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis x is approximately empty; enlarging it (it is [0.0:0.0]) on input line 40.
```

Specifying the axis limits removes the warning. Additionally, the example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [mark=*] (0,0) 
     \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
      {  -- ++(1,0.1*\x) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

does not compile at all. Replacing `\foreach` by `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` does not help.

Is there away to specify the increments in `\addplot`?

Comment: `--` is `\draw` syntax -not `\addplot` syntax. You can not use `\foreach` inside `axis`. -search for "foreach pgfplots" e.g. : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment

Comment: Yes, I was surprised that `--` actually compiles here. In any case, how would I go about drawing a line based on increments rather than points in `pgfplot`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things at play here.

1. You need at least an `\addplot` command if you want automatic scaling in an `axis` environment --- otherwise, you need to scale it manually;
2. As said by @hpekristiansen, `foreach` does not work as expected in an `axis` environment, and you have to resort to `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`;
3. In an `axis` environment, the (default since 1.11) `axis cs:` coordinate system accepts only absolute coordinates; [you need to use the `axis direction cs:` coordinate system to do incremental moves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332603/38080);
4. And finally, it seems that using the correct coordinates the `\foreach` does work, as notice by [@hpekristiansen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609026/38080).

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % you need to manually scale the axis if you do not use "addplot"
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5]
      % let's unfold the "foerach" manually to see how it works
      % with the correct coordinate system
      \draw[red] (0,0) -- ++ (axis direction cs:1,0.1) 
          -- ++(axis direction cs:1,0.2)
          -- ++(axis direction cs:1,0.3)
          -- ++(axis direction cs:1,0.4)
          -- ++(axis direction cs:1,0.5);
      % to have the "foreach" function, we must use "pgfplotsinvokeforeach",
      % which accepts only full statement. Let's use a 
      % temporary coordinate to simulate the "last point"
      \coordinate (last) at (0,-0.5);
      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5}{%
        \draw[blue] (last) -- ++ (axis direction cs:1,0.1*#1) coordinate(last);}
       % in this case the plain foreach seems also to work
       % I do not know why...
       \draw[green] (0,-1) \foreach \x in {1,...,5} 
            { -- ++ (axis direction cs: 1,0.1*\x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Just to check, is there no way to have a single draw command like before? I mean of course the draw command being outside the loop and having the for loop construct the path.

Comment: @Tohiko I think it's impossible --- I tried a bit of expansion tricks to no avail. I will be happy to be wrong! ;-)

Comment: I think that @hpkristiansen found the solution (added, thanks!)

Comment: +1. I need to look into `axis direction cs:`. This could also be made with marks!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the command `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` (taken from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264168/pgfplots-use-foreach-inside-addplot) answer).

Here is the code. (I've also changed the `--` from your `addplot` to `coordinates`. This was taken from the [PGFPlots Gallery](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html).)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1, ..., 5} {
                \addplot coordinates {
                    (0, 0)
                    (1, 0.1*#1)
                };
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and generates this image:

[image: multiple addplot]

---

### Edit

I misunderstood the question before.
The following should work, although it might not be the *"best"* solution.
I define a coordinate `(current)` from which I draw the next segment. Then I define a coordinate `(tmp)` (using `\path`) where the next position is and then I redefine `(current)` to be `(tmp)`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
        ]
    
    \coordinate (current) at (axis cs: 0, 0);
    
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1, ..., 5} {
        \draw[mark=*] (current) -- ++(axis cs: 1, 0.1*#1);
        \path (current) ++(axis cs: 1, 0.1*#1) coordinate (tmp);
        \coordinate (current) at (tmp);
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Alternatively you could use `\coordinate (tmp) at ($(current)+(axis cs: 1, 0.1*#1)$);` to define `(tmp)`, though this requires `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` in the preamble. Sadly, apparently one needs to pass in `xmin`, ..., `ymax` manually, if `addplot` is never used (at least nothing is drawn for me, if I don't pass them in manually).
This is the generated picture:

[image: continuous plot]

Comment: This creates five different plots. -I do not believe that is what OP is after.

Comment: Notice that `mark=*` does not work as an argument of `\draw`...

Answer (score 2):

`samples at` already has a `\foreach` syntax, so there is no need to use `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[mark=*, samples at={0,...,5}] (\x, 0.1*\x);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Linear graph]

**Edit:**

Here is a solution, that does not use `\addplot` but `\draw` - also a solution that adds marks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=12, ymin=-1, ymax=10]
    \draw[thick] (0,0) \foreach \x in {1,...,5} { -- ++ (1,0.1*\x)};
    \draw[red] (0,0) \foreach \x in {1,...,5} { -- plot[mark=*] coordinates { ++(1,0.1*\x)}};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

This does not work right now because I used `\foreach` inside `axis` - it need to be rewritten with PGFPlots variants of `\foreach`.

**Edit:**

I found that it is not possible to do it like that with PGFPlots variants of `\foreach`. An alternative is to use a named coordinate as in the answer by @Simon, so that it can be drawn piecewise. -but with `plot`, so that marks can be made:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=2]
\coordinate (current) at (0, 0);  
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1, ..., 5} {
  \draw (current) -- plot[mark=*] coordinates {++(1, 0.1*#1)} coordinate (current);
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with marks]

For some reason, the entire plot changes when `xmin` is changed to e.g. `-1`. I can not explain this strange behaviour.

Comment: This does not plot increments but the actual points. If the increment are (1,1) (2,2) and (3,3), the points should be at (1,1), (3,3) and (6,6). This is what `\draw (1,1) --  ++(2,2) -- ++(3,3);` would do.

Comment: `\addplot[mark=*, samples at={0,...,5}] (\x, 0.5*0.1*\x*\x+0.5*0.1*\x);` follows same line as `\draw (0,0) \foreach \x in {1,...,5} { -- ++ (1,0.1*\x)};`

Comment: Thanks. As I said in my original post. I simplified the example. The real case (or a Brownian motion) has to be described with increments.

Comment: @Tohiko: I do not know how to do that. Why not just use `\draw` inside `axis`?

Comment: Hmmm... the last point `y` should be at 0.1+0.2+0.3+0.4+0.5 = 1.5, no? It works if you use `\draw[green] (0,-1) \foreach \x in {1,...,5} { -- ++ (axis direction cs: 1,0.1*\x)};`